# WebSocket connection to failed ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: ssl, websocket

I have configured the Websocket on my live server and I'm using SSL on live server. When I used following code on my localhost, websockets were fine.

```
ws://localhost:8080/server.php
```

Once I moved the file to the live server I have changed the code to the following

```
wss://IP:PORT/server.php
```

I have created a seperate port for web socket and configured on firewall TCP IN and OUT. However, I'm receiving the following error on console

> WebSocket connection to ............ failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Can anyone suggest me some solutions to overcome this issue

Comment: If you just moved the setup to a live server it does not get automatically SSL enabled (i.e. wss:// vs. ws://). What makes you think that wss:// should work?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich This is my first attempt on Websocket. I'm not much familiar with WS. That's why seeking help here

Answer (score 13):

Basically when you are using `wss` you are just serving the `WebWocket` over `SSL/TLS`.

Meanwhile using a simple `ws` does not require a particular setup, `wss` does. Indeed you have to create a secure connection using a valid **SSL Certificate** when opening the communication.

If you certificate is `missing` or `invalid` the connection cannot be  enstabilished therefore an error will be raised while attempting to start the communication.

So you can't just switch from `ws` to `wss` but also have to make a proper implementation.

You can find [**more details here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404160/why-does-my-wss-websockets-over-ssl-tls-connection-immediately-disconnect-w), hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

here is what I did, I never able to install ssl in local, so I started using the w3cwebsocket client

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

and test it in console using

```
 node index.js
```

> var W3CWebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;    var client =
> new W3CWebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:7000/');  console.log(client)