# TLS with dynamic server ip

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is like to use TLS for a websocket client from browser javascript.

The problem is the server is started dynamically by talking to a REST service and when started an endpoint ip is returned.  I.e the server is an ec2 onstance that has a new unique ip when started.  That endpoint will not have a dns name and so when doing tls the certificate will not match against the ip.

I'd there a way to bypass the dns name check but still complete the connection and have the benefit of an encryped session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this
[Why does my wss:// (WebSockets over SSL/TLS) connection immediately disconnect without giving any errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404160/why-does-my-wss-websockets-over-ssl-tls-connection-immediately-disconnect-w)

> The key to the problem is this: If your SSL certificate causes a
>   warning of any sort, wss:// WebSocket connections will immediately
>   fail, and there is no canonical way to detect this.

It seems that you are using self-generated certificates issued to an IP. Certificates are usually issued to server names, but also can be bound to an IP address
[Are SSL certificates bound to the servers ip address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095780/are-ssl-certificates-bound-to-the-servers-ip-address)

But in this case, if IP changes your TLS connection will give a warning from the client, so the browser will disconnect

You could use a dynamic DNS with dynamic IPs with a wildcard certificate. For example

Certificate issued to
*.domain.com

DNS

```
conn1.domain.com -> IP1
  conn2.domain.com -> IP2
  conn3.domain.com -> IP3
```

If you can not work with a totally dynamic DNS, i could suggest use a fixed range of IP-names and certificates issued to this ip. select the appropriate certificate when you know the ip at launch time

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure i like to rely on dynamic dns.  Is a horrible thing but we'll see